# Only stacking markers with the same location

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The Clustering tool from google maps clusters all markers depending on zoom level.

I'm attempting to (Only) stack together the markers with the same location.
Then segue and pass the array of information into a tableview when pressed. What could be a potential solution?

Would the best solution be to merge duplicate coordinates to a single marker prior to adding them to the map somehow? or attempt to use google maps clustering tool somehow?

Current code:

Created array

```
var events = [CreatedEvent]()
```

Retrieving custom markers (Single).

```
weak var createdevent:CreatedEvent?

func createNewMarker(firebasePath: CollectionReference) {
        
        let Eventref = firebasePath
            Eventref.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                
                if err == nil && querySnapshot != nil {
                    var tempEvent = [CreatedEvent]()
                    if querySnapshot!.documents.count > 0 {
                        self.mapIsEmpty = false
                        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                            
                            let data = document.data()
                            let author = data["author"] as? [String:AnyObject]
                            let uid = author!["uid"] as? String
                            let username = author!["username"] as? String
                            let photoURL = author!["photoURL"] as? String
                            let url = URL(string:photoURL!)
                            let eventname = data["eventname"] as? String
                        
                            let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: uid!, username: username!, photoURL: url!)
                            let createdevent = CreatedEvent(eventid: document.documentID, author: userProfile, eventname: eventanme)
                            
                            let marker = GMSMarker()
                            self.createdevent = createdevent
                            
                            if let dict = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ImageCache") as? [String:String] {
                                if let path = dict[createdevent.eventphotoURL.absoluteString] {
                                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {

                                        let imageA1 = UIImage(data: data)
                                        let customMarker = CustomMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.customMarkerWidth, height: self.customMarkerHeight), image: imageA1!)
                                        marker.iconView = customMarker
                                        marker.userData = createdevent
                                    
                                    }
                                }
                            }
   
                            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: eventlatitude, longitude: eventlongitude)
                            marker.map = self.myMapView
                            
                            tempEvent.append(createdevent)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
        
                        print("no data")
                    }
                    self.events = tempEvent
                }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The clustering mechanism is only useful when there are multiple markers but here there is only one. And that's because there's no point in adding multiple markers to the same location because it's wasteful and if the markers are tappable then only the last marker added could produce action.

Consider keeping an index of markers and rely on it instead of the map itself. Always add markers to the index but only add them to the map where there aren't already markers. Then when a marker is tapped, go to the index and if there is only a single marker there then push the user to that detail and if there are multiple markers there then display a list of those markers to the user from which to choose from. Here is something you can run in a Playground (otherwise change `NSObject` to `GeoPoint` to make it a proper subclass):

```
/* A GeoPoint is an NSObject with 2 properties (lat and lon).
 We can subclass it to add an identifer which will give
 us a string key for our index (a concatenation of lat and lon). */
class GPoint: NSObject {
    let identifier: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        identifier = "\(latitude)\(longitude)"
    }
}

// This represents the marker that is added to the map
struct Marker {
    let identifier: String
    let geoPoint: GPoint
}

// This represents the marker index
var mapMarkers = [String: [Marker]]()

func addMarkerToMap(_ marker: Marker) {
    let geoId = marker.geoPoint.identifier // get the marker's “location”
    
    if mapMarkers.contains(where: { $0.key == geoId }) {
        print("add to index")
        mapMarkers[geoId]?.append(marker) // a marker exists here only add marker to index
    } else {
        print("add to map and index")
        mapMarkers[geoId] = [marker] // no marker here yet, add to map and index
    }
}

let marker1 = Marker(identifier: "abc123", geoPoint: GPoint(latitude: -118.1, longitude: 33.3))
let marker2 = Marker(identifier: "mno789", geoPoint: GPoint(latitude: -117.0, longitude: 34.8))
let marker3 = Marker(identifier: "xyz456", geoPoint: GPoint(latitude: -118.1, longitude: 33.3))

addMarkerToMap(marker1)
addMarkerToMap(marker2)
addMarkerToMap(marker3)
print(mapMarkers)
```

This mechanism also allows us to add different-looking markers to the map to denote which ones represent stacked markers and which don't.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is what i'm looking for. I'll try it out tomorrow when i have time.